# Hide sidebar or show small side bar for web app

Tags: navigation, sidebar

I am looking for feedback on the navigation structure for a web application.

In the application, we have:

- A sidebar on the left where all the projects are listed
- A list of views with all the tasks of the selected project
- A task card detail

We have an issue with real estate when the 3 columns are open.

I like the idea to be on focus mode and I have proposed the idea to drill down the navigation to show only what is relevant to the user.

If a user opens a task card detail, the sidebar disappears. The goal is to allow the user to focus on the project: 
[image]

The other option (which is really popular) is to collapse the sidebar.
The issue is the user may open the sidebar and end up with 3 columns which can be overwhelming [image]

What do you think? Which option works best?
Thanks

Comment: mmm it will depend on a lot of variables: how much time does users spend interacting with a task? how often they are likely to switch between task? and between projects? How many task does a project will have as maximum?

Answer (score 2):

The reliance of your users on the current project and the frenquency at which switching project occurs is going to dictate the design chose here. At first glance this one works best. The space remains manageable and should allow you to make it work for more desktop/tablet screen sizes. This is however very dependant on the content of the tasks as well, if it requires lots of space, it is more appropriate.

[image]

I would also propose another approach, the advantage here is that the current project is persistant.

[image]

Hope this helps!